# Android app Facebook login returns null value or nothing

Tags: android, facebook

I have been having this issue for a bit now and I can't seem to find the solution. I have tried the graph API as well as the Profile tracker. Both seems to be giving issues. The Graph API lets the application crash with a null object reference for the users ID and when using the profile tracker, the application doesn't continue beyond that part.

Here is my code with the tracker commented out and the graph API being used.

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                /*if(Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null) {
                    profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                        @Override
                        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile2) {
                            // profile2 is the new profile
                            Mint.leaveBreadcrumb("Login Activity ~ Waiting for facebook to return profile");
                            Log.v("facebook - profile", profile2.getFirstName());
                            profileTracker.stopTracking();
                        }
                    };
                    // no need to call startTracking() on mProfileTracker
                    // because it is called by its constructor, internally.
                }
                else {
                    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                    Mint.leaveBreadcrumb("Login Activity ~ Current Profile" + profile);
                    Mint.leaveBreadcrumb("Login Activity ~ Current FBID" + profile.getId());

                    SetUserData();
                    LogIn();
                    ///
                    continueToAdverts();
                }*/

                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                                try {

                                    //String name = object.getString("name");
                                    //String email = object.getString("email");
                                    //String id = object.getString("id");
                                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name + " " + " " + email + " " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    AppGlobal.LoggedUser = new UserInfo();
                                    AppGlobal.LoggedUser.setFacebookId(object.getString("id"));
                                    SetUserData();
                                    LogIn();
                                    ///
                                    continueToAdverts();

                                } catch (JSONException ex) {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code

            }
        });
```

Am I missing something?